# Trying to use openpyxl to iterate over 2 colums to find specific row

Tags: openpyxl

I want to find a specific value in column B and column C and use that info to designate the correct row.  Unfortunately, the values in column B repeat.

Let's say I need to find a row that has ABC in Column B and 123 in column C. I need the script to iterate over both columns until it finds a match and then I need it to provide the row number that the values were found on

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, after perusing stackoverflow and various other resources.
Basically, I created a list out column B and a list out of column C. I zipped those lists together to create one long tuple and then I used enumerate to find the row that the pair of values I was looking for was located on.

By all means, if anyone has a more pythonic solution I would be glad to hear it.

For the code below, the values I'm looking for is 3964729 in column B and 18 in column C

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("E:\\VoiceCore\\NSS HANDOVER NEW(5).xlsx")
ws = wb['Jan 20~ Jan 26']
#Creates a list of column B values
wo = []
for col in ws['B']:
    wo.append(col.value)
#Creates a list of column C values
task = []
for col in ws['C']:
    task.append(col.value)
#zips both lists in a tuple
woTask = zip(wo,task)
#enumerates the tuple
woRow = [i for i, e in enumerate(woTask, 1) if e == (3964729, 18)]
'''The woRow variable spits out row 78, which is the row that I was looking for, 
but its type is list. I then do a for loop to extract the value out of the list to 
get an integer, which I use for further processing'''      
for i in woRow:
    woRowInt = i
```